# configure openCV Qt new functions

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opencv3.0

I'm struggling with the step from the official documentation

> Extract it into a nice and short named directory like D:/OpenCV/dep/qt/ . Then you need to build it. Start up a Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) by using the start menu search (or navigate through the start menu All Programs ‣ Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ‣ Visual Studio Tools ‣ Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)).
>
> The Visual Studio command prompt
> Now navigate to the extracted folder and enter inside it by using this console window. You should have a folder containing files like Install, Make and so on. Use the dir command to list files inside your current directory. Once arrived at this directory enter the following command:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools
          -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg
```

...

My issue is that in this document Qt 4.7.3 was used, now, I dont know about that version because I wasn't able to find it but in the newer one there is not Install, Make files...

which ones should I use instead?

does anyone has any step for more recent version of Qt and VS that I can follow to get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out I wasn't using the source file, which you can find [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.zip) found the folder which contains the configuration and INTALLS files on the new version in a folder called qtbase continued with the steps from there on the OPENCV guide and everything worked alright on MSVS2012